Can banno digital toolkit create custom stand alone pages?
I apologize if this is common knowledge but is it be possible for an FI to create say their own custom "Card Controls" page using the tools available for us through Banno? A plugin not connected to the dashboard page. It's own stand alone page.
We are probably searching poor but we couldn't find a direct answer using either the Digit Toolkit developer knowledge base or the general Jack Henry knowledge base.

In short, yes. I'll grab some screenshots to help illustrate how that works. It boils down to 'navigate directly to the Redirect URI in your browser', and if you have the OAuth/OpenID Connect auth flow working well, your page will recognize that it needs to connect to Banno to authenticate the user.

The short answer
Yes, you could build your own page which would 'stand alone' but still use Banno's Authentication Framework.
While you certainly could make that page do double duty as a plugin card...you may not necessarily want to do that if you're looking to have the user consent to some external connected app.
The long answer
Here's an example plugin from the Build Your First Plugin quickstart.
This screenshot shows navigating to the plugin via the Dashboard in the Garden demo institution.

Instead of navigating through Banno's UI, you could navigate directly to the Redirect URI that's used in configuring the plugin. In this case, thats http://localhost:8080/dynamic and this is what that would look like, using the same plugin example:

That would get you what you literally asked for in the question. While I don't have an animation to show the redirection and login to Banno (if the user isn't already logged in), I hope this illustrates the idea.
However, that's really only useful if you're hoping to make the application do double duty as both a 'stand alone' page as well as as plugin card. Which could work in high trust environments i.e. you trust the developer who built the app (which may indeed be yourself).
If you want to have the user go through the Consent experience for connected apps, then you could simplify this down to using just the Authentication Framework without having to configure a plugin card.
Here's what that would look like, using a different quickstart...Authentication (Node.js Example).
In this case, I navigate directly to the Redirect URI for that sample project, http://localhost:8080/login.html, directly in my web browser.
I'm not logged into Banno, so I get this page:

If I click that button, I get redirected to Banno and see this consent screen. (Ignore the specific details of what the consent screen is asking for, as I quickly whipped up this example...but hopefully you get the gist.)

If I consent to authorize the app, I'll be connected and see this screen. The screen is more of a technical debugging screen, but imagine that was showing a pretty UI instead.

NOTE:
That consent experience is meant to be used to let users consent to connecting their account to an external application. It's meant to let users have informed consent in terms of what the external application is empowered to do (based on what the user saw in the consent screen). That's NOT to be confused with a 'Terms & Conditions', 'Terms of Service', or other "speed bump" sign-up screens.

While you could certainly build something like that as part of your experience, it doesn't come out-of-the-box from the Digital Toolkit itself.

